# Как массово стилизовать изображения в что-то похожее на Prisma?

Tags: ubuntu, изображения

Не обязательно именно Prisma, можно что-то похожее.
У меня Ubuntu, желательно каким-то скриптовым методом (bash, php, python, программы или еще что-то)
Изображений примерно 2.5 тысячи. Хотелось бы все это провернуть бесплатно.
Для тех кто не слышал о Prisma, примерно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

например, можно воспользоваться возможностями пакета программ *imagemagick* (входит в репозитории всех популярных дистрибутивов). а чтобы не углубляться во все сложности и тонкости, можно воспользоваться, например, уже готовым скриптом [cartoon](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cartoon/) (в конце, на всякий случай, я скопировал его содержимое).

например, вот такой командой я сделал нечто примерно похожее на проиллюстрированный вами эффект:

```
$ ./cartoon -e 0 исходный.файл файл.с.результатом
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

применяя различные опции скрипта, можно добиться и различных результатов. ещё большего можно добиться, изучив, как и с какими опциями этот скрипт вызывает *imagemagick* (точнее, программу *convert*).

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Developed by Fred Weinhaus 3/6/2013 .......... revised 8/8/2015
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 
# Licensing:
# 
# Copyright © Fred Weinhaus
# 
# My scripts are available free of charge for non-commercial use, ONLY.
# 
# For use of my scripts in commercial (for-profit) environments or 
# non-free applications, please contact me (Fred Weinhaus) for 
# licensing arrangements. My email address is fmw at alink dot net.
# 
# If you: 1) redistribute, 2) incorporate any of these scripts into other 
# free applications or 3) reprogram them in another scripting language, 
# then you must contact me for permission, especially if the result might 
# be used in a commercial or for-profit environment.
# 
# My scripts are also subject, in a subordinate manner, to the ImageMagick 
# license, which can be found at: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 
####
#
# USAGE: cartoon [-p pattern] [-n numlevels] [-m method] [-e edgeamount] 
# [-b brightness] [-s saturation] infile outfile
# USAGE: cartoon [-h or -help]
# 
# OPTIONS:
# 
# -p      pattern           segmentation pattern (shape); 0<=integer<=100;
#                           default=70
# -n      numlevels         number of desired segmentation levels; integer>=2;
#                           default=6
# -m      method            edge method; 1 or 2; default=1
# -e      edgeamount        amount of edges; float>=0; default=4
# -b      brightness        brightness of cartoon; integer>=0; default=100
# -s      saturation        saturation of cartoon; integer>=0; default=100
# 
###
# 
# NAME: CARTOON 
# 
# PURPOSE: To create a cartoon-like appearance to an image.
# 
# DESCRIPTION: CARTOON creates a cartoon-like appearance to an image. The 
# image is smoothed and then multiplied by a grayscale version of the image 
# with the desired number of levels to produce the segmented appearance.  
# The pattern parameter changes the shape of the segmentation for the given 
# number of levels. Edges are then superimposed onto the image. 
# 
# 
# ARGUMENTS: 
# 
# -p pattern ... PATTERN is the pattern or shape of the segmentation. Values 
# are between 0 and 100. The default=70.
# 
# -n numlevels ... NUMLEVELS is the desired number of segmentation levels.  
# Values are integers>=2. The default=6.
# 
# -m method ... edge METHOD. Choices are 1 or 2. The default=1. 
# 
# -e edgeamount ... EDGEAMOUNT is the amount of edges to overlay on the 
# cartoon. Values are floats>=0. The default=4.
# 
# -b brightness ... BRIGHTNESS of the cartoon. Values are integer>=0. The
# default=100 (no change).
# 
# -s saturation ... SATURATION of the cartoon. Values are integer>=0. The
# default=150.
# 
# CAVEAT: No guarantee that this script will work on all platforms, 
# nor that trapping of inconsistent parameters is complete and 
# foolproof. Use At Your Own Risk. 
# 
######
# 

# set default values
pattern=70          # segmentation pattern; 0<=integer<=100
numlevels=6         # numlevels; integer>=2
method=1            # edge method; 1 or 2
edgeamount=4        # edge amount; float>=0
brightness=100      # brightness; integer>=0
saturation=150      # saturation; integer>=0

# fixed arguments
edgewidth=2         # edge width; integer>=0
edgethresh=90       # edge threshold; 0<=integer<=100
edgegain=4          # edge gain for method=2

# set directory for temporary files
dir="."    # suggestions are dir="." or dir="/tmp"

# set up functions to report Usage and Usage with Description
PROGNAME=`type $0 | awk '{print $3}'`  # search for executable on path
PROGDIR=`dirname $PROGNAME`            # extract directory of program
PROGNAME=`basename $PROGNAME`          # base name of program
usage1() 
    {
    echo >&2 ""
    echo >&2 "$PROGNAME:" "$@"
    sed >&2 -e '1,/^####/d;  /^###/g;  /^#/!q;  s/^#//;  s/^ //;  4,$p' "$PROGDIR/$PROGNAME"
    }
usage2() 
    {
    echo >&2 ""
    echo >&2 "$PROGNAME:" "$@"
    sed >&2 -e '1,/^####/d;  /^######/g;  /^#/!q;  s/^#*//;  s/^ //;  4,$p' "$PROGDIR/$PROGNAME"
    }


# function to report error messages
errMsg()
    {
    echo ""
    echo $1
    echo ""
    usage1
    exit 1
    }


# function to test for minus at start of value of second part of option 1 or 2
checkMinus()
    {
    test=`echo "$1" | grep -c '^-.*$'`   # returns 1 if match; 0 otherwise
    [ $test -eq 1 ] && errMsg "$errorMsg"
    }

# test for correct number of arguments and get values
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
    # help information
   echo ""
   usage2
   exit 0
elif [ $# -gt 14 ]
    then
    errMsg "--- TOO MANY ARGUMENTS WERE PROVIDED ---"
else
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
        do
            # get parameter values
            case "$1" in
          -h|-help)    # help information
                       echo ""
                       usage2
                       exit 0
                       ;;
                -p)    # get pattern
                       shift  # to get the next parameter
                       # test if parameter starts with minus sign 
                       errorMsg="--- INVALID PATTERN SPECIFICATION ---"
                       checkMinus "$1"
                       pattern=`expr "$1" : '\([0-9]*\)'`
                       [ "$pattern" = "" ] && errMsg "--- PATTERN=$pattern MUST BE A NON-NEGATIVE INTEGER VALUE (with no sign) ---"
                       test1=`echo "$pattern < 0" | bc`
                       test2=`echo "$pattern > 100" | bc`
                       [ $test1 -eq 1 -o $test2 -eq 1 ] && errMsg "--- PATTERN=$pattern MUST BE AN INTEGER BETWEEN 0 AND 100 ---"
                       ;;
                -n)    # get  numlevels
                       shift  # to get the next parameter
                       # test if parameter starts with minus sign 
                       errorMsg="--- INVALID NUMLEVELS SPECIFICATION ---"
                       checkMinus "$1"
                       numlevels=`expr "$1" : '\([0-9]*\)'`
                       [ "$numlevels" = "" ] && errMsg "--- NUMLEVELS=$numlevels MUST BE A NON-NEGATIVE INTEGER VALUE (with no sign) ---"
                       test=`echo "$numlevels < 2" | bc`
                       [ $test -eq 1 ] && errMsg "--- NUMLEVELS=$numlevels MUST BE AN INTEGER GREATER THAN 1 ---"
                       ;;
                -m)    # get  method
                       shift  # to get the next parameter
                       # test if parameter starts with minus sign 
                       errorMsg="--- INVALID METHOD SPECIFICATION ---"
                       checkMinus "$1"
                       method=`expr "$1" : '\([0-9]*\)'`
                       [ "$method" = "" ] && errMsg "--- METHOD=$method MUST BE A NON-NEGATIVE INTEGER VALUE (with no sign) ---"
                       test1=`echo "$method <= 0" | bc`
                       test2=`echo "$method >= 3" | bc`
                       [ $test1 -eq 1 -o $test2 -eq 1 ] && errMsg "--- METHOD=$method MUST BE EITHER 1 or 2 ---"
                       ;;
                -e)    # get  edgeamount
                       shift  # to get the next parameter
                       # test if parameter starts with minus sign 
                       errorMsg="--- INVALID EDGEAMOUNT SPECIFICATION ---"
                       checkMinus "$1"
                       edgeamount=`expr "$1" : '\([.0-9]*\)'`
                       [ "$edgeamount" = "" ] && errMsg "--- EDGEAMOUNT=$edgeamount MUST BE A NON-NEGATIVE FLOAT VALUE (with no sign) ---"
                       ;;
                -b)    # get brightness
                       shift  # to get the next parameter
                       # test if parameter starts with minus sign 
                       errorMsg="--- INVALID BRIGHTNESS SPECIFICATION ---"
                       checkMinus "$1"
                       brightness=`expr "$1" : '\([0-9]*\)'`
                       [ "$brightness" = "" ] && errMsg "--- BRIGHTNESS=$brightness MUST BE A NON-NEGATIVE INTEGER VALUE (with no sign) ---"
                       ;;
                -s)    # get saturation
                       shift  # to get the next parameter
                       # test if parameter starts with minus sign 
                       errorMsg="--- INVALID SATURATION SPECIFICATION ---"
                       checkMinus "$1"
                       saturation=`expr "$1" : '\([0-9]*\)'`
                       [ "$saturation" = "" ] && errMsg "--- SATURATION=$saturation MUST BE A NON-NEGATIVE INTEGER VALUE (with no sign) ---"
                       ;;
                 -)    # STDIN and end of arguments
                       break
                       ;;
                -*)    # any other - argument
                       errMsg "--- UNKNOWN OPTION ---"
                       ;;
                 *)    # end of arguments
                       break
                       ;;
            esac
            shift   # next option
    done
    #
    # get infile and outfile
    infile="$1"
    outfile="$2"
fi

# test that infile provided
[ "$infile" = "" ] && errMsg "NO INPUT FILE SPECIFIED"

# test that outfile provided
[ "$outfile" = "" ] && errMsg "NO OUTPUT FILE SPECIFIED"

# setup temporary images
tmpA1="$dir/cartoon_1_$$.mpc"
tmpB1="$dir/cartoon_1_$$.cache"
tmpA2="$dir/cartoon_2_$$.mpc"
tmpB2="$dir/cartoon_2_$$.cache"
trap "rm -f $tmpA1 $tmpB1 $tmpA2 $tmpB2;" 0
trap "rm -f $tmpA1 $tmpB1 $tmpA2 $tmpB2; exit 1" 1 2 3 15
trap "rm -f $tmpA1 $tmpB1 $tmpA2 $tmpB2; exit 1" ERR

# get im version
im_version=`convert -list configure | \
sed '/^LIB_VERSION_NUMBER /!d;  s//,/;  s/,/,0/g;  s/,0*\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1/g' | head -n 1`

# colorspace RGB and sRGB swapped between 6.7.5.5 and 6.7.6.7 
# though probably not resolved until the latter
# then -colorspace gray changed to linear between 6.7.6.7 and 6.7.8.2 
# then -separate converted to linear gray channels between 6.7.6.7 and 6.7.8.2,
# though probably not resolved until the latter
# so -colorspace HSL/HSB -separate and -colorspace gray became linear
# but we need to use -set colorspace RGB before using them at appropriate times
# so that results stay as in original script
# The following was determined from various version tests using cartoon.
# with IM 6.7.4.10, 6.7.6.10, 6.7.7.7, 6.8.3.7
if [ "$im_version" -lt "06070607" -o "$im_version" -gt "06070707" ]; then
    setcspace="-set colorspace RGB"
else
    setcspace=""
fi
if [ "$im_version" -le "06070707" ]; then
    proc="-gamma 2.2"
else
    proc="-colorspace sRGB"
fi
# no need for setcspace for grayscale or channels after 6.8.5.4
if [ "$im_version" -gt "06080504" ]; then
    setcspace=""
    proc="-gamma 2.2"
fi

# read the input image into the temporary cached image, convert to depth 8 and selective blur
convert -quiet "$infile" +repage -depth 8 -selective-blur 0x5+10% "$tmpA1" ||
    errMsg "--- FILE $infile DOES NOT EXIST OR IS NOT AN ORDINARY FILE, NOT READABLE OR HAS ZERO size  ---"

ww=`identify -ping -format "%w" $tmpA1`
hh=`identify -ping -format "%h" $tmpA1`

# set up median filter
if [ "$im_version" -ge "06060806" ]; then
    medproc="-statistic median 3x3"
else
    medproc="-median 1"
fi


# convert to grayscale and posterize to create mask image
# convert $tmpA1 -level 0x$pattern% $setcspace -colorspace gray -posterize $numlevels -colorspace $cspace -depth 8 $tmpA2
convert $tmpA1 -level 0x$pattern% $setcspace -colorspace gray -posterize $numlevels -depth 8 $proc $tmpA2

if [ $method -eq 1 ]; then
    # process image
    # multiply the blurred posterized graycale mask with the smoothed input
    # convert smoothed input to grayscale
    # negate and blur
    # colordodge composite the grayscale and negated/blurred version to make edgewidth image
    # use power to amplify and then threshold and median filter
    # multiply composite the edgewidth with the blended image
    convert $tmpA1 \( $tmpA2 -blur 0x1 \) \
        \( -clone 0 -clone 1 -compose over -compose multiply -composite -modulate $brightness,$saturation,100 \) \
        \( -clone 0 $setcspace -colorspace gray \) \
        \( -clone 3 -negate -blur 0x${edgewidth} \) \
        \( -clone 3 -clone 4 -compose over -compose colordodge -composite \
            -evaluate pow $edgeamount -threshold $edgethresh% $medproc \) \
            -delete 0,1,3,4 -compose over -compose multiply -composite "$outfile"
elif [ $method -eq 2 ]; then
    # process image
    # multiply the blurred posterized graycale mask with the smoothed input
    # convert smoothed input to grayscale
    # apply high pass filter to grayscale, use power to amplify and threshold
    # multiply composite the edge image with the smoothed color image
    convert $tmpA1 \( $tmpA2 -blur 0x1 \) \
        \( -clone 0 -clone 1 -compose over -compose multiply -composite -modulate $brightness,$saturation,100 \) \
        \( -clone 0 $setcspace -colorspace gray -negate -define convolve:scale=$edgegain \
            -morphology Convolve DoG:0,0,${edgewidth} -negate \
            -evaluate pow $edgeamount -white-threshold $edgethresh% \) \
        -delete 0,1 -compose over -compose multiply -composite "$outfile"
fi

exit 0
```